# ASP.NET beginner question: How do I implement something like this is my ASP.NET C# website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create an FAQ page like the one on this website

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/faq.aspx

When you click on the question, the answer expands. Click it again and it collapses.

My question, answers are stored in a database. I googled and found out there's this JavaScript code to achieve this BUT also came across something that said it can be done using Repeater Controls.

How to do that? Any link to some tutorial would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery. Suppose you have a page name `Faq.aspx`.
So put this code into your .aspx page.

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery_div.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //hide the all of the element with class msg_body
            $(".msg_body").hide();
            //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
            $(".msg_head").click(function(){
                $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle(600);
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .msg_head {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        background-color:#F4F4F8;
        color:Blue;
        margin:1px;
    }
    .msg_body {
        padding: 5px 10px 15px;
        background-color:#F4F4F8;
    }
    </style>
</head>
```

In the body tag you have to put this code.

```
<body>
    <p class="msg_head">your titel</p>

    <div class="msg_body">
        Your logic
    </div>
</body>
```

I really hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 4):

It's called an [accordion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_%28GUI%29).

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

jQuery can do this :)

A repeater and jQuery can be used together. It depends on the structure of the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Found few links for you. Hope these might help you -

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/asp-net-repeater-control

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10040295/repeater-control.aspx

Comment: thnx but it doesn't say anything about collapsible text :(

Comment: @happysoul - The collapsible text are due to javascript as Paddy and stefanvds have suggested in other answers.

Comment: ok..now I need to figure out how to make them work together..thnx for the links

Comment: @happysoul - Yes, exactly. You can use repeater control to show all your questions and for each question the collapsible answers can be implemented using other links.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a repeater to display the questions and answers (the answer in a `div` with `visibility=hidden`).  You then need some JavaScript code (probably worth looking at the jQuery library to make this easier) to hook the click event of the question to show the answer on the client side.

The repeater is used because you have a 'repeating' layout, it makes this a bit simpler.  You need the JavaScript code because you want the visual effect to happen on the client side.